# How many cores/threads does cublas_sgemm uses?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, cublas

I am new to GPU and parallel programming .
I want to execute a function say 'A' parallel-ly  on different data say x1,x2,x3.... 
'A' calls the function 'cublas_sgemm' .

Then whether or not I have to care about implementation of cublas_sgemm ?

Comment: sounds like you want to call `cublas_sgemm` from within your custom CUDA kernel, right? why don't you want to use the host API?

Comment: in simple terms, I want to call cublas_sgemm on different data at the same time . So How do I know the optimal number of instances of cublas_sgemm that can be called while optimising performance  (given that I know maximum dimension of matrix)?

Comment: GPU cores are designed to be oversubscribed. It is required for performance. If you have a task to complete in the minimum time, just launch all the parallel operations as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be concerned about the implementation of cublasSgemm.  It will use as much of the device as is possible for the problem size.  For reasonably large matrices, it will utilize the whole device.  For any function that effectively utilizes the whole device, you're not likely to observe much improvement in performance by trying to add additional parallelism (vs. just issuing the gemm functions in sequence, with appropriate use of overlap of copy and compute).

For small matrices, there is a [batched gemm function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemmbatched) that should be better than trying to manage the parallelism yourself.